# Не работает мой код C++

Tags: c++, if, while

Дана переменная a. Пользователь вводит a с консоли. Необходимо выводить переменную a, только если она нечетная, и увеличивать ее, пока она меньше 1000.

как я сделал

```
 int doc;doc = 0;
            cout <<"Введите число: ";cin >> doc;
            while(doc = 1000) 
            {
                doc++;
                if(doc % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Число - " << doc << " Четное" << endl;         
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"увеличивать ее, пока она меньше 1000"* - `while(doc = 1000)` В знаке "меньше" опечатались.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В условии должно быть <, а не =. Плюс, у вас вывод сейчас происходит, если число чётное. Чтобы выводилось нечётное, надо изменить условие на `if(1 == doc % 2)`. В результате получается следующий код:

```
int doc = 0;
cout <<"Введите число: ";
cin >> doc;
while(doc < 1000) {
    if(1 == (doc % 2)) {
        cout << "Число - " << doc << " Нечетное" << endl;         
    }
    doc++;
}
```